# parsing json array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php function that returns json data that looks like this:

```
    if ($result !== false) 
    {
        $resultdata = array(
        'status' => true,
        'error_msg'=>'',
        'data' => $result
        );
    }
    else 
    {
        $resultdata = array(
        'status' => false,
        'error_msg'=>"Unable to reassign port vlan.  Check Port mode.",
        'data' => $result
        );

    }       
    header ('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($resultdata);
```

The data from the model ($result) is built like this:

```
    $pattern = "/([0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+)(\s+)([a-z]+)(\s+)([a-z]+)(\s+)/i";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $this->_data, $matches)) 
    {
      $vlandetailsArray['VlanId']= $matches[1];
      $vlandetailsArray['Name']= $matches[3];
      $vlandetailsArray['Egress']= $matches[5];
      $vlandetailsArray['Type']= $matches[7];
    }
```

And the code in my view looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
                  url:fullpath,
                  type:'POST',
                  dataType:'json',
                  success: function(returnDataFromController) {
                    console.log(returnDataFromController);
                    if (returnDataFromController.status == true)
                    {
                      //build table contents 
                      var htmlstring = '<thead>';  
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr>';
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>VlanId</th>';
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Name</th>';
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Egress Rule</th>';
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Port Membership Type</th>';
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tbody>';
                      //should only be one entry so no need to loop

                     // htmlstring = htmlstring + "<tr>"
                      //htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class ='vlanid'>" + returnDataFromController.VlanId + "</td>";
                      //htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController.Name + "</td>";
                      //htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController.Egress + "</td>";
                     // htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController.Type +"</td>";
                      //htmlstring = htmlstring + "</tr>";      

                      $('#assignedvlans').html(htmlstring);
                      $('#progress-indicator').hide();

                      }

                      else

                      {
                                  alert('my error message: ' + returnDataFromController.error_msg);
                      }
                                },//end success
                error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                          alert(errorThrown);
                }
```

What I'm wondering is how to access the "data" section of my return array, and the "error_msg".  Right now, after the ajax is executed, when the status is false, the alert that appears shows "my error message:undefined".  But I'm not getting any error messages about "returnDataFromController.status"

As far as the data is concerned, I've tried :

```
 returnDataFromController.data.VlanId
```

and

```
 returnDataFromController["#data"].VlanId
```

but neither one seems to work.  The code that's been commented out used to work when i wasn't returning a wrapper array around the data .  i was previously just returning "$result" from the controller...

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
By the way, the console.log doesn't really help me much.  For some reason, in the web console, i don't see any data being dumped there.  I'm using firefox...

**UPDATE 2**

When the controller returns true for the status, this is the error message I get from the ajax error handler:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

I have changed my code to use:

```
 returnDataFromController.data.VlanId
```

**UPDATE 3**

To simplify matters, I tried to recreate my problems using more basic code.  To that end, here's my controller:

```
public function test()
{
    $mydata = array(
      'VlanID'=>80,
      'Name'=>'test vlan'
    );
   $data = array(
      'status'=> true,
      'error_msg'=>'all is well',
      'data'=>$mydata
   );
    header ('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

And here's my view:

```
    $('#testbutton').click(function() {             
            $.ajax({                  
                url:'http://myserver/myapp/index.php/controller/test/',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(returnDataFromController) {   
                 alert('success');
                 console.log(returnDataFromController);
                                    alert(returnDataFromController.data.VlanID);
                  },//end success
                error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                     alert('ajax error handler: ' + errorThrown);
                }                     
              }); //end ajax call
```

When i click on the test button, this is what happens: 
1.  i get the first alert that says "success".
2. nothing is written to the console
3. i get the following error message in the console - when trying to do the second alert "TypeError:  returnDataFromController.data is undefined".

hope this example simplifies things and helps to id where I'm going wrong.
thanks.

**UPDATE 4**

When I add:

```
   alert(returnDataFromController.toSource());
```

I get the following output:

```
      ({VlanID:80, Name:"test vlan"})
```

Comment: `returnDataFromController.data` should return the correct object. However, we can't tell from your PHP what's inside that data. Please show us `$result`

Comment: You already have `console.log(returnDataFromController)` in there. What does the returned object look like? You should be able to browse it in the console.

Comment: Incidentally, `if (returnDataFromController.status == true)` can be simplified to `if (returnDataFromController.status)`

Comment: Blazemonger, i dunno if you saw my latest update.  i just finished including the code that shows what the model returns for data....

Comment: @Berkowski - it doesn't show me anything in the console.  I've tried both IE and also firefox.

Comment: hava you checked the $resultdata (its value exist or not) before encoding it to json? You could use chrome if console.log() doesn't work in firefox

Comment: @Yagi, I tried in chrome. i still don't get anything for console.log ... but the message box that appears says "unexpected token <".  This is when status is true.

Comment: please see my updated post for a simpler example i was able to create.

Comment: What do you get when you do `alert(returnDataFromController.toSource())` ?

Comment: @EmCo, i get the following:({VlanID:80, Name:"test vlan"})

Comment: So, the problem is that you're encoding `$mydata` , not `$data` in json_encode.

Comment: Emco, that's correct!  I fixed it now so that I'm encoding data instead of mydata. and it's working. now i'm going to see if I figure out why my real code is breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $('#testbutton').click(function() {             
        $.ajax({                  
            url:'http://myserver/myapp/index.php/controller/test/',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(returnDataFromController) {   
             alert('success');
             console.log(returnDataFromController);
            alert(returnDataFromController.VlanID);
              },//end success
            error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                 alert('ajax error handler: ' + errorThrown);
            }                     
          }); //end ajax call
```

Comment: EmCo, that gives me the following error in the console: TypeError: myData is undefined.

Comment: I edited it. As I said in a comment on the original question, you're encoding the array named `$mydata` when you should be encoding `$data` .

Comment: yeah... so i'm trying to see if i can see the difference between my test and the real code.

Comment: @dot It might help if you do ` alert(returnDataFromController.toSource());` to your original response to see what it's like.

Comment: it doesn't get into the success part. it  goes into the ajax calls' error handler, where I have the alert(errorThrown).  It says: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character. Is there any way to dump out my data from my controller so i can see what the data looks like before I do a json encode?  I tried var_dump or print_r on the array but because the output is set to json on the view, nothing shows up...

Comment: Try removing the `header` part.

Comment: you can make a var_dump before encoding the data and use a tool like firebug to see how your data looks like when the script is called.

Comment: Emco... the problem was in the way the data was being generated in the model!  But your suggestions helped me troubleshoot.  Thanks.